# ¿Cómo automatizar el cálculo del precio de entrada promedio para cada nuevo precio de entrada y tamaño de contrato agregado en una hoja de Excel?

Tags: excel, formulas, función-personalizada

## Contexto

- ***Precio de Entrada*** (*o [Punto de Entrada](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/entry-point.asp#:%7E:text=An%20entry%20point%20refers%20to,order%20for%20a%20short%20position.)*) *se refiere al precio al que un inversor inicia una posición en un activo. Una entrada comercial puede iniciarse con una orden de compra para una posición larga o una orden de venta para una posición corta.*
- ***Precio Promedio de Entrada*** *se refiere al precio central al que se posiciona un inversionista en un activo para aumentar las ganancias potenciales y salir del mercado más fácilmente, esta métrica puede tomar diferentes precios de entrada así como diferentes cantidades de contratos (o [tamaño de contratos](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/contractsize.asp#:%7E:text=our%20editorial%20policies-,What%20Is%20Contract%20Size%3F,the%20terms%20of%20the%20contract.))*

### Cálculo manual del Precio Promedio de Entrada en una Hoja de Excel

Basado en [este artículo](https://www.bybit.com/fr-FR/help-center/bybitHC_Article?language=fr&id=000001113), logré calcular el Precio Promedio de Entrada de la siguiente forma:

- Suponga que tiene los siguientes **Precios de Entrada:**
  `[16500,16400,16300,16200]`
- Además, suponga que tiene las siguientes **Cantidades de Contratos** ancladas a esos **Precios de Entrada** de manera respectiva:
  `[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]`

Tal información será almacenada en la siguiente tabla:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 |  |
| 16400 | 0,1 |  |
| 16300 | 0,1 |  |
| 16200 | 0,1 |  |

Ahora, las fórmulas de los precio de entrada promedio correspondientes se escribieron de la siguiente manera (suponga que el nombre de posición de las columnas es A, B, C respectivamente):

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | `=B3/(B3/A3)` |
| 16400 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4)/(B3+B4)` |
| 16300 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4+A5 * B5)/(B3+B4+B5)` |
| 16200 | 0,1 | `=(A3 * B3+A4 * B4+A5 * B5+ A6*B6)/(B3+B4+B5+B6)` |

Finalmente, los resultados fueron los siguientes:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | 16500 |
| 16400 | 0,1 | 16450 |
| 16300 | 0,1 | 16400 |
| 16200 | 0,1 | 16350 |

## Problema

¿Cómo podría automatizar el cálculo del **Precio promedio de entrada** para cada nuevo valor de **Precios de entrada** y **Cantidad** pegado en la última fila de la tabla? El resultado esperado sería algo como esto:

| Entry Price | Quantity (BTC) | Average Entry Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16500 | 0,1 | 16500 |
| 16400 | 0,1 | 16450 |
| 16300 | 0,1 | 16400 |
| 16200 | 0,1 | 16350 |
| 16100 | 0,1 | 16300 |
| 16000 | 0,1 | 16250 |
| 15900 | 0,1 | 16200 |

Answer (score 1):

Puedes calcular el output deseado utilizando la función promedio pero que el rango sea parcialmente dinámico, bloqueando solo una de las referencias:

En mi imagen la fórmula es:

```
=PROMEDIO($A$3:A3)
```

Fíjate bien que la primera coordenada del rango está bloqueada pero la segunda no. Hemos hecho un rango parcialmente dinámico que va creciendo según arrastras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya veo, es una buena solución, aunque no sé sí tiene en cuenta los valores de la columna B3 (los de `Quantity (BTC)`), ¿qué pasaría sí los valores de dicha columna fuesen todos distintos?

Comment: @NoahVerner Pon un ejemplo con los datos correctos que mencionas entonces a ver si es posible.